Problem with aleph Examen Class
I am trying to create an exam using Aleph-Examen Class. I wonder I am doing everything right but I dont see the mistake on this code.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PREÁMBULO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{etex} 
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{aleph-examen}
%SI QUIERES RTAS
%\documentclass[12pt,letter,respuestas]{aleph-examen}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PAQUETES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Comandos Matemáticos
\usepackage{aleph-comandos}
%Multiples Columnas
\usepackage{multicol}
%Graficas poderosa
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%Emojis
\usepackage{wasysym}
%Ubicacion Estricta
\usepackage{float}
%links
\usepackage{hyperref}
%Colores
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%definiciones
\usepackage{mathtools}

%%%%%%%%%%%% DATOS EXAMEN %%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Datos de la prueba
\institucion{Instituto Alberto Merani}
\carrera{Contextual A, Alfa y Aleph}
\autor{Germán López - Heidy Luengas}
\asignatura{Estructuras Algebraicas}
\tema{Nivel 2 - Fecha 2}
\fecha{Trimestre 3 2024}
\logouno[3.5cm]{Imagenes/Logo_IAM.jpg}

%Color de Respuestas
\definecolor{colortext}{RGB}{0,179,225}
\definecolor{cian}{RGB}{0,179,225}

%Propósito
\newcommand{\Proposito}{
\noindent \textbf{Propósitos del Trimestre:} 
\begin{enumerate}[label = \textbf{P\arabic*}]
    \setcounter{enumi}{1}
    \item Demostrar las propiedades de las operaciones en la estructura algebraica de los números racionales. 
    \item Emplea las propiedades de las operaciones en la resolución de problemas.
\end{enumerate}

\noindent \textbf{Propósito de la prueba:} Demostrar mediante Nivel 2 la apropiación de las propiedades y resolución de problemas con números racionales.
}

\newcommand{\puntos}[1]{\textbf{[#1 Puntos]}}

\newcommand{\comentar}[1]{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENTO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\encabezado

\vspace{1cm}

\Proposito

\begin{indicaciones}
    \item El siguiente documento contiene una serie de preguntas que buscan que demuestre su dominio de los temas trabajados en el trimestre.
    \item Recuerde completar el examen solo en este documento.
    \item Cuenta con las dos horas de clase para completar el ejercicio. 
\end{indicaciones}
    \section*{Operaciones con números racionales}
\begin{preguntas}
    \item  Una bella pregunta.
    \begin{respuesta}
        Este es el problema
    \end{respuesta}
\end{preguntas}
\end{document}

When compiling it Overleaf, throughs an error..

I already uploaded aleph-examen.cls class and also the aleph-comandos.sty commands package.

May you help me to identify the mistake? Something I noticed is that the issue is with the enviroment "respuesta". When I delete from exam it works perfectly. However, I need it for pressenting solutions to my students.
The class version I'm using is from GitHub (the official, no beta): https://github.com/alephsub0/LaTeX_aleph-examen/blob/main/aleph-examen.cls
The aleph-comandos package comes from GitHub (the official, no beta): https://github.com/alephsub0/LaTeX_aleph-comandos/blob/main/aleph-comandos.sty

Please make your document self-contained and specify, which versions of aleph-examen.cls and aleph-comandos.sty you use (downloaded from where). If I pick whatever Google suggests first, I get the error "undefined control sequence \universidad". This means that we cannot reproduce your problem with the information provided, and therefore cannot help.

Oh no, it was provided form my institution. I will redownload from official webpage

I already present a link to download! Thanks for corrections!!

please copy-paste error messages as text. images can't be indexed, searched or parsed by screen reading software. in this case, copy the first error message from the log file - not the abridged version overleaf displays initially. this gives you more information about the problem including the line number. (this may not help much with a runaway argument, but it tells you the problem isn't later in the file, at least.)

The problem is in the indentation of \end{respuesta}.
The class uses comment to exclude answers and does \excludecomment{respuesta}, but the documentation of comment is clear about \end{<envname>} being at the beginning of the line, with no indentation.
If you change your document environment into
\begin{document}

\encabezado

\vspace{1cm}

\Proposito

\begin{indicaciones}

\item El siguiente documento contiene una serie de preguntas que buscan
      que demuestre su dominio de los temas trabajados en el trimestre.
\item Recuerde completar el examen solo en este documento.
\item Cuenta con las dos horas de clase para completar el ejercicio.

\end{indicaciones}

\section*{Operaciones con números racionales}

\begin{preguntas}

\item  Una bella pregunta.

\begin{respuesta}
Este es el problema
\end{respuesta}

\end{preguntas}

\end{document}

it's clearer and, more important, it works.

Remove \RequirePackage{etex}. It used to be necessary sometimes about till ten years ago, now it's definitely recommended not to load etex.
